# At what age should siblings stop sharing their bedroom?

Tags: age-appropriate, siblings, bedroom

Currently we have one bedroom for our two daughters. Until what age can they share their room?

Comment: +1 nice question, i have heard (but somewhat doubt) it's a legal requirement here in the UK for this to cease at a certain age for mixed sex siblings ... any answers which can add any legal information would be welcome.

Comment: or perhaps my question about mixed-sex siblings should be a separate question if @Andra is specifically asking about same-sex

Comment: @hawbsl yes please make it a separate question as the issues at stake are completely different.

Comment: When did the "same-sex" entered the question?

Comment: In some cultures, several generations all sleep in the same room. So there's no general, cross-cultural answer here.

Comment: @hawbsl - I can't find any legislation on requiring separation of sexes. It seems to be a general recommendation, but not law.

Comment: I always thought it was the age of reason. 7 years old. I thought that children of mixed sexes couldn't share a room when they were seven or older.

Comment: Originally there was a law in Uk forbidding bedroom sharing for brothers & sisters above the age of puberty. However, that law has apparently been repealed.

Comment: The question is about two girls, in which case I'm not sure the same reasoning applies.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Having one's own room can be *nice*, but it's never a necessity.  It's only in the last generation or two that it became common to give children separate bedrooms instead of just having a boys' room and a girls' room.

Comment: Yup, my answer would be 'when the first one leaves home' :)

Comment: +1.  The only year my brother and I didn't share a room was the year I was in middle school and he was in elementary, which meant we woke up at different times.  We continued to share a room up until I left for college.

Comment: Surely the question was should, not must?

Answer (score 12):

Same-sex siblings don't **need** separate rooms, at least not if they're roughly the same age. Sharing a room teaches valuable social lessons. It's more a matter of how well they get along in general, and how much space you can afford.

I wouldn't put a 2-year-old in a room with a 12-year-old though, or two siblings that terrorize each other.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be any law in the UK to stop children of the *opposite* sex sharing a room ([advice on overcrowding](http://england.shelter.org.uk/get_advice/repairs_and_bad_conditions/overcrowding)) - which makes sense. I can't see why the same wouldn't be true for mainland Europe. So I think we can assume that children of the *same* sex can share a room as well.

With no legal reason compelling your daughters to sleep in separate rooms it becomes a personal choice. I can't say when they should stop sharing as that will be different for each set of siblings, but my 2 boys won't be separated unless I think it is affecting their sleep. Obviously as they get older the criteria may change.

Comment: I could not imagine any law like that being passed nor controlled except in shelters like you link to

Comment: Shelter is a uk charity dealing with housing problems, including homelessness.

Answer (score 3):

As one of 5 I shared a room with 1 brother and a sister for many years, then as elder siblings began to leave home we all started to get our own rooms:-)

My suggestion - make do with whatever space you have. If they fight and you can't solve that problem, then it may make sense to split them up, but otherwise it will depend on the space you have in your house/flat etc